# How to configure Apache init scripts, after compiling and installing the sources?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I installed Apache using this script https://gist.github.com/Benedikt1992/e88c2114fee15422a4eb

The system is a freshly installed CentOS 6.7 minimal system.

After installation I can find the apache in /usr/local/apache2/ but I can't start the apache with `service` or enable start on boot with `chkconfig`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a problem with CentOS packages?

Comment: There is no Apache 2.4 in the default packages. With EPEL (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138899/centos-install-using-yum-apache-2-4) it is not compiled with --enable-so

Comment: Did it not install an init script?

Comment: within /etc/init.d is no init script for apache (or httpd)

Comment: and on `/usr/local/etc`?

Comment: there is just one configuration file (pear.conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache 2.4 doesn't use the init scripts. As Saul Ortega said the apachectl script can be used to start the server. It can also be used as a standard SysV init script. Further informations can be found in the apache doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/invoking.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I install apache on centOS, it gets installed in `/etc/httpd/conf/` check there, otherwise do a `find / -name httpd` or `find / -name apache`. Also, if I want to start it now you start/stop it with `sudo systemctl httpd start/stop` or `httpd -k start` or `apachectl start`

Comment: with apachectl I can start the server. Nevertheless I can't use chkconfig or service

Comment: well, you don't need `chkconfig` or `service` because they are deprecated now. You should use `systemctl` instead.

Comment: I use centos 6. There is no systemd